# How to translate zip file to svf format more than 1 times

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

currently I'm working on forge IDA, workflow of our code is sending xml file as input through web page(web page just has upload button). and taking ipt files & drawing sheet from BIM360,after performing workitem, storing the output.zip file in bucket. as of now Bundle(code) is working fine, next implementation is showing output(assembly file) on webpage (viewer).

now I'm able to translate zip file(I referred this tutorial for translation:- 1.https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-zip-to-stl/
2.https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/forge-aspnet-zero-hero-30-minutes).

But as everytime file store in bucket with same name and overiding existing output.zip file, so while translate file for first time I got 'success' result after that I'm getting result as 'Created' & file doesn't get translate and showing same file(first file where I got result as success) on viewer.

webpage and forge application are independent application they are communicating with each other using API.

how can I translate zip file multiples times and show it on viewer?

any reply is appreciable.

Thank you
Siddhesh Nikam

how can I translate zip file multiple times present in bucket and show it on viewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [force a new translation](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/jobs/job-POST/) on the same file using the `x-ads-force` header if you want, but then you still have to deal with the previous design showing in the Viewer as the resources are cached by the browser.

What we suggest is using new file names for new versions of the same model. All the relevant information including links to other blog posts are available here: 
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/file-versioning-buckets

Comment: thank you so much for your reply @AdamNagy
this link is also helpful
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-keeps-showing-old-model